# Angular CLI e2e & useFactory switching

Tags: angular, protractor, angular-cli

I'm trying to come up with a pattern for an Angular 4 provider factory such that i can switch the implementation used when `ng e2e` is run.

I've looked into trying to do something with [build environments](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/1.1.x/docs/documentation/build.md#build-targets-and-environment-files) in angular-cli, but running into issues with `ng serve -e e2e`

```
$ ng serve -e e2e
Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at createSourceFile (/home/user/Documents/workspace/ngproj/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:15457:109)
    at parseSourceFileWorker (/home/user/Documents/workspace/ngproj/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:15389:26)
    at Object.parseSourceFile (/home/user/Documents/workspace/ngproj/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:15338:26)
    at Object.createSourceFile (/home/user/Documents/workspace/ngproj/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:15192:29)
    at VirtualFileStats.getSourceFile (/home/user/Documents/workspace/ngproj/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/compiler_host.js:66:35)
    at WebpackCompilerHost.getSourceFile (/home/user/Documents/workspace/ngproj/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/compiler_host.js:213:38)
    at findSourceFile (/home/user/Documents/workspace/ngproj/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:67909:29)
    at processImportedModules (/home/user/Documents/workspace/ngproj/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:68056:25)
    at findSourceFile (/home/user/Documents/workspace/ngproj/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:67937:17)
    at processImportedModules (/home/user/Documents/workspace/ngproj/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:68056:25)
    at findSourceFile (/home/user/Documents/workspace/ngproj/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:67937:17)
    at processImportedModules (/home/user/Documents/workspace/ngproj/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:68056:25)
    at findSourceFile (/home/user/Documents/workspace/ngproj/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:67937:17)
    at processSourceFile (/home/user/Documents/workspace/ngproj/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:67840:27)
    at processRootFile (/home/user/Documents/workspace/ngproj/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:67728:13)
    at /home/user/Documents/workspace/ngproj/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:67018:60
```

Disregarding that specific issue, does anyone have a good pattern for Provider Factories and switching implementations based upon cli arguments or specific environments (such as detecting the app is being run via `ng e2e`)

```
const authFactory = (http) => {
  if (environment.useRestApi) {
    console.log('Using HTTP REST Api')
    return new HttpAuthService(http);
  } else {
    console.log('Using In Memory REST Api')
    return new InMemoryAuthService();
  }
};

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    HttpModule
  ],
  declarations: [],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: AuthService,
      useFactory: authFactory,
      deps: [Http]
    }
  ]
})
export class AuthModule {
}
```

I'm not interested in using `MockBackend` / `MockConnection` (i've used these in my .spec.ts files to test `HttpAuthService`)

### Update on stack trace

The stack trace was caused by a typo in my .angular-cli.json file:

```
  "environments": {
    "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
    "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts",
    "e2e": "environments/environments.e2e.ts"
  }
```

Here the referenced e2e file had an extra 's' in the file name. As is always the case, it was sure nice of ng-cli/webpack/ts/node to tell me this in an obvious way.

I'm still open to alternatives so i'll leave this as an update vs an answer (in the hope that and unanswered question may gather more interest), but for the meantime, using an environment works for me